# C#: Find ImageButton given its ID as a string and update the imageURL

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I need to update the imageURL of an imageButton of given ID in C#?
I tried using: **FindControl()**, but I got a **null** value as result

**In ASPX Page**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Cards/1.gif" onClick="Image_Click"/>
```

**In C# code**

```
ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton)FindControl("imgBtn1");
```

I am getting **imgButton = null**

I create a button **Reset** which calls the method **btnReset_Click** and in this method I need to find the imageButton:

```
protected void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton)FindControl("imgBtn1");
}
```

Comment: can you please add your code?

Comment: This question is unanswerable in it's current form. Post relevant code and markup and explain clearly what the problem is.

Comment: How does it look like in the aspx? Where is this imgBtn1 declared and how does it look like? :-) It will be easier to help you if you post both sides. (That means, not just the exact line from the code behind) There are lots of things that can have happened here.

One of them could be that you have not properly set up "imgBtn1" to  begin with and/or you're trying to access it before its been initialized. Where and in what function are you running this code above?

Comment: have you checked that FindControl is called from your **load** event and not from c'tor or init event?

Comment: I am not calling from Load. Is this the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldnt need to use FindControl("imgBtn1"), as the designer in visual studio should have generated the necessary object for you to use.

Can you access it by just typing:

```
ImageButton imgButton = imgBtn1;
```

Perhaps?

**EDIT**

Try the following code and see if it works for you :)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton imgButton = FindControl<ImageButton>("imgBtn1", this);
    }

    public T FindControl<T>(string name, Control current) where T : System.Web.UI.Control
    {
        if (current.ID == name && current is T) return (T)current;

        foreach (Control control in current.Controls)
        {
            if (control.ID == name && control is T)
            {
                return (T)control;
            }

            foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
            {
                var ctrl = FindControl<T>(name, child);
                if (ctrl != null && ctrl.ID == name) return ctrl;
            }
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I can access throught this. But I have a string ID "imgBtn1" and I need to access through this string.